# Virtual Host Displays Two out of Three Sites

Tags: command-line, server, apache2, virtualhost

I have setup apache2 to use three domains. They are pointed correctly and I have setup the sites-available config files as the following:

Here is hfd-server.domain1.com, this one displays the default APACHE2 success page. However, it works with www.hfd-server.domain1.com. Don't understand.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin email@domain1.com
        ServerName www.hfd-server.domain1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/hfd-server.domain1.com/public_html
        ServerAlias hfd-server.domain1.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        #Other Directives Here
        <Directory /var/www/hfd-server.domain1.com/public_html>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here are the other two working config files:

**house.domain1.com**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin email@domain1.com
        ServerName www.house.domain1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/house-server.domain1.com/public_html
        ServerAlias house.domain1.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        #Other Directives Here
        <Directory /var/www/house.domain1.com/public_html>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**house.domain2.com**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin email@domain1.com
        ServerName www.house.domain2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/house.domain2.com/public_html
        ServerAlias house.domain2.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        #Other Directives Here
        <Directory /var/www/house.domain2.com/public_html>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The access log and error log shows nothing out of the ordinary. Not sure why one would work but not the other one.

I didn't modify 000-default.conf. I was afraid to, so I made copies and just enabled them.

Is there anything else I can try, HFD-SERVER.domain1.com is linked to a control panel that I would like to have access.

**UPDATE 12-28-17**

I used sudo apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS and this is what it listed.

```
VirtualHost configuration: *:80  is a NameVirtualHost
default server HFD-SERVER.domain1.us (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
port 80 namevhost hfd-server.domain1.us (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
port 80 namevhost www.hfd-server.domain1.us (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/hfd-server.domain1.us.conf:1) alias hfd-server.domain1.us
port 80 namevhost house.domain1.us (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/house.domain1.us.conf:1) alias www.house.domain1.us
port 80 namevhost house.domain2.us (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/house.domain2.us.conf:1) alias www.house.domain2.us
```

Appears that the default server is 000-default.conf. Is there a way to make the hfd-domain1.us.conf  the default server?

Comment: I dont think it would make a difference but if this was me .. I would most likely use `ServerName hfd-server.domain1.com` and `ServerAlias www.hfd-server.domain1.com` making the server name without the www and the alias with the www.. for all the entries ... in the sites-enabled folder what entries are in there is it the 000-default.conf along with the 3 new conf files you created? sounds like there is something different about the hfd-server config file .. not really sure what to suggest .. they all end in `.conf`. I found apache2 didnt like when I had config files that werent labeled `.conf`

Comment: I would also use `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` to see if all your virtual hosts are listed

Comment: I ran the command. I updated the question with the information. Appears that the default server is the 000-default.conf file. It's overwriting the hfd-server.domain1.us file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in a few different ways

Change the `000-default.conf` replace the relevant lines to match the  `hfd-domain1.us.conf` and deleting the `hfd-domain1.us.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` then it would be the "000-default.conf" that points to the proper hdf-domain1.us with the proper folder structure and the other two would be show up as they did in the dump.

another way would be to change the `000-default.conf` and change the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` entries to something different so they dont have the same name as in `hfd-domain1.us.conf` and then you would have a default site pointing to these new settings .. and the 3 virtual ones you created.

and the last way is to go to the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` directory and remove or rename the shortcut to `000-default.conf` changing the extension to `000-default.conf~`

Updated:
this was pointed out that it doesn't seem to allow you just to remove the file so I updated this answer with the information by the original poster the best way for this would be to run `sudo a2dissite 000-deafult.conf` to remove the 000-default.conf thus leaving the 3 virtual hosts enabled and should function as you want.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the right answer because you gave me a good place to look. I tried renaming the default conf file and it broke apache. Apache wouldn't start because the site was still enabled. I realized that you can use **sudo a2dissite 000-deafult.conf** to disable the default config and it will take the first config file in its place. It resolved all issues. Thank you.

Comment: ok glad you got it all figured out .. sorry about forgetting about the a2dissite command .. I never had to use that in the old days .. guess this is something new in updated versions of Apache2